# How can I reclassify the raster with xarray in python

Tags: python, numpy, raster, python-xarray

I have **LAI = xarray.DataArray 'band_data' (y: 1460, x: 1480) **
with the values from 0 to 1.8, I want to reclasify the raster to four classes:

```
0 - 0.4 = 1 
0.4 - 1 = 2 
1 - 1.4 = 3 
1.4 - 1.8 = 4
```

I try:

```
LAI[np.where((LAI>1.4))]=4
LAI[np.where((LAI>1.0)&(LAI<1.4))]=3
LAI[np.where((LAI>0.4)&(LAI<1.0))]=2
LAI[np.where((LAI<0.4))]=1
```

```
LAI[xr.where((LAI>1.4),4)]
LAI[xr.where((LAI>1.0)&(LAI<1.4),3)]
LAI[xr.where((LAI>0.5)&(LAI<1.0),2)]
LAI[xr.where((LAI<0.5),1)]
```

but it was not working.

Is there any possibilities how to do it with xarray.where?

Thanks

Comment: Based on docs (https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html) shouldn't that be `LAI = xr.where(LAI > 1.4, 4, LAI)`?

Comment: Do you mean like this? xr.where(LAI>1.4,4,LAI)
xr.where((LAI>1.0)&(LAI<1.4),3,LAI)
xr.where((LAI>0.5)&(LAI<1.0),2,LAI)
xr.where((LAI<0.5),1,LAI) it does nothing it return the same data

Comment: Replace the works with a vectorized `searchsorted`

Comment: Is there any specific reason that your bins are of unequal size? They're all 0.4 except one which is 0.6. Without other context this seeks like an error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `where` for this, you can use a boolean expression on its own, e.g.

```
LAI[LAI > 1.4] = 4
```

But I wouldn't do this either because [`np.digitize()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) does what you want. It works on DataArrays too, for example:

```py
import xarray as xr

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
data = 1.8 * rng.random(size=(10, 10))
da = xr.DataArray(data)
bins = [0, 0.4, 1.0, 1.4, 1.8]
np.digitize(da, bins=bins)
```

The result is:

```
array([[3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3],
       [3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4]])
```